# Organize an array?

Tags: php, database

I am getting data from the DB like this

```
// Get WPDB Object
global $wpdb;

// Table name
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "postmeta";

$layers = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT meta_value FROM $table_name WHERE meta_key =    '_moon_sortable_content'" );
```

Then I echo out all the values

```
// Iterate over them
foreach($layers as $key => $value) {
          foreach($value as $breakingbad) {
             echo $breakingbad;
          }          
}
```

It returns `Beach Day? || 309px || 838px || Array`  Four values.. where I am a little confused is how to turn each value into a variable, for example.

```
$top = 309px
$left = 838px
$content = Beach Day?
```

I would suspect something like this perhaps `$breakingbad['top'], $breakingbad['left'], $breakingbad['content']` (yes I was watching breaking bad while writing this lol). I see this all the time, I am just not sure the proper way to do it, it would be great to learn the proper terms so I can google this info, and any links to tuts related to this would be awesome, also your insight would make my day!

**Results of var_dump:**

```
object(stdClass)#282 (1) { ["meta_value"]=> string(21) "I am changing text..." }
object(stdClass)#283 (1) { ["meta_value"]=> string(20) "288.00001525878906px" }
object(stdClass)#284 (1) { ["meta_value"]=> string(5) "808px" } 
object(stdClass)#285 (1) { ["meta_value"]=> string(5) "Array" }
```

**Here is what the table looks like:**

[image: metatable]

Comment: looks like a bad database schema to begin with...

Comment: Why is that.. Could you explain?

Comment: i dont know what he means but based on your db schema there is no way to 100% determine which value is which. What I mean on this is, if you select the meta_key too and the metakey is something like "topVal" and "metavalue" equals "808px" that would be fine, but like this it's just not possible. On the otherhand something like `Array` should never enter your db, since `Array` appears in 99% of the cases when you tried to save a variable which is an array. Same thing happens if you try to do an `echo` on a variable which is an array.

Comment: I am not sure where the array is comming from, inside my script I am only adding data from a textarea and from one input field that holds my top and left values, I have to figure out how to stop adding that value to the DB... but I am trying to use the data like `$breakingbad['top']` I see that in many plugins (most data is all in one column)

Answer (score 0):

well `$value` is your array containing those 4 values. Which means you have to do `$value['top']` for the top.

I suggest you learn something about array.
Think of arrays as a list of variables. Each variable can be access by a key.

Comment: Ok, how do I associate a specific array out of those four to equal $value['top'].. I am sure its easy, I just learn things like a 4th grader..

Comment: well it already is, if you are unsure about the keys try a `var_dump($value);die;` this outputs the contents of value including datatype and keys. Actually is all the naming already done by your query. The Key names are the corresponding  table names. If you take them from one field, you should try selecting another field which makes a unique combination.

Comment: Ok, cool I used var_dump before but I didnt know how to take advantage of what it outputs, I ran it again and I posted in the OP what the results were.. They are all [meta_value]

Answer (score 0):

Use [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode):

```
$string = "Beach Day? || 309px || 838px || Array";
$string = explode(" || ", $string);

$top = $string[1]; // 309px 
$left = $string[2]; // 838px
$content =  $string[0]; //Beach Day?
```

Codepad: http://codepad.org/WVGR5Nd7

Comment: What if the data is constantly changing though?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

```
// Iterate over them
foreach($layers as $key => $value) {
   foreach($value as $breakingbad) {
  // split string with || as delimiter             
  $split = explode('||', $breakingbad);
  $content = $split[0];
  $top = $split[1];
  $left = $split[2];
  $array = $split[3];

 }          
}
```

Do note that this work only if the string formatting for each piece of data is consistent. Your last item is an array, so you have to iterate through it to retrieve its values.

Comment: Yeah ill deal with that last value later... I am not sure where its coming from to be honest the most important are the first three...

Comment: So far this is working, still fiddling with it, thanks again.. Ill post back here soon..